# Projecting a polygon into a bounding box

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

I am trying to fit the boundaries (ignoring the center edge `G`) of two connected polygons (by means of projection) into a rectangular bounding box, similar to below :

[image]

The criterion is that such that

- the resultant polygon does not overlap with itself.
- the winding order is still preserved (e.g. `ABCDEF` in a counter-clockwise direction will still be mapped to `A'B'C'D'E'F'`).
- No 2 sides of the polygon become colinear after the projection (e.g. `DEF` are 3 sides of a polygon, therefore `D'E'F'` should be on 3 different sides of the bounding box as well).

Now intuitively we know the ideal mapping (for example, `E` is best projected to the bottom of the box as opposed to the right of the box), however,

Is there a general algorithm to determine the best direction (top, bottom, left, right) for projection, given a polygon?

Comment: *"for example, E is best projected to the bottom of the box as opposed to the right of the box"* You may know this intuitively since you understand your own requirements, but it's not clear to me why E shouldn't be projected left instead of downwards; nor why F shouldn't be projected downwards. What is the condition for one projection being "better" than another?

Comment: The condition is that the resultant projection should not result in a polygon that is self-intersecting

Comment: But that is satisfied whether you project E left or down; so why is down "better"?

Comment: If you are guaranteed that the polygon is [Star-Shaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-shaped_polygon), you can project each point onto the rectangle using a point from the kernel of the polygon. Finding a point in the kernel is described in the linked article.

Comment: However, from the example you provided, you seem to project the same point at two different places on the rectangle, making the projected polygon discontinuous. Is it what you want? You should specify a bit more what are the requirement of the projection. Algorithms exist for mapping closed curves, but it depends on your requirements.

Comment: @kaya3 I have updated the question to be clearer. The winding order of each polygon has to remain consistent before and after the projection.

Comment: But projecting E left instead of down doesn't change the winding order!

Comment: Can  anyone define the meaning of "project" here for the plebs like me? :) From the picture given, I cannot see any change in the shape of the polygon. Only the points of the polygon being horizontally and vertically connected to a bounding square.

Comment: @kaya3 Updated again for a colinearity condition. Sorry English is not my first language. So in this case projecting `E` to the left means `D'E'` will lie on the same side of the bounding box, which breaks the condition

Comment: @BitTickler project means just a normal vector projection. the dotted lines represent the projection onto the bounding box

Comment: And what determines the size of the square? It could be smaller, to the same effect... or bigger...

Comment: @BitTickler the size is arbitrary as long as it encompasses the entire set of polygons.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé Yes it is fine. I have updated the question to reflect the colinearlity and winding order conditions. hope it is clearer

Comment: As for up/down vs left/ right, could it be as easy as: ``let d = p2 - p1 in let r = d.y/d.x in if abs r > 1 then then LEFT_OR_RIGHT else BOTTOM_OR_TOP`` ?

Comment: Can you draw the new polygon after projection in your example? Does the new polygon have twice the number of vertices? cuz it looks like you project each vertex onto two different edges.